# How to import sun.audio?

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

I am attempting to play audio for a program and I need the AudioStream class and the AudioPlayer class, but when I attempt to import them Eclipse gives me an error.

Method where used:

```java
public static void playMusic(String filepath) {

        InputStream music;
        try {
            music = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(music);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error"); 
        }
    }
```

Imports:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
```

Comment: You need to add the error that you're getting to help someone answer!

Comment: The sun audio classes were never part of the official Java API and in recent versions of Java don't exist at all. You should use the [tag:javasound] APIs.

Comment: I know what problem he's getting. `sun.audio`'s been removed since JDK 9. I'm just clarifying upon @greg-449 's comment above.